# How to Get Data from a Multi-Level PHP Object to Store in a Wordpress CPT

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I need to go through the four levels of this php object, skipping the first one and defining the hierarchy of the others to be able to load it into a Custom Post Type with ACF

```
    object(stdClass)#15623 (5) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["nome"]=>
  string(38) "Tribunal de Justiça do Estado do Acre"
  ["sigla"]=>
  string(4) "TJAC"
  ["unidades"]=>
  array(22) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#15784 (5) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(13)
      ["nome"]=>
      string(10) "Rio Branco"
      ["sigla"]=>
      string(2) "RB"
      ["unidades"]=>
      array(69) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#15856 (5) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(116)
          ["nome"]=>
          string(39) "Diretoria de Tecnologia da Informação"
          ["sigla"]=>
          string(5) "DITEC"
          ["unidades"]=>
          array(3) {
            [0]=>
            object(stdClass)#15857 (5) {
              ["id"]=>
              int(196)
              ["nome"]=>
              string(41) "Gerência de Banco de Dados e Segurança "
              ["sigla"]=>
              string(5) "GEBAN"
              ["unidades"]=>
              array(0) {
              }
              ["tipo"]=>
              string(14) "ADMINISTRATIVA"
            }
            [1]=>
            object(stdClass)#15858 (5) {
              ["id"]=>
              int(197)
              ["nome"]=>
              string(19) "Gerência de Redes "
              ["sigla"]=>
              string(5) "GERED"
              ["unidades"]=>
              array(0) {
              }
              ["tipo"]=>
              string(14) "ADMINISTRATIVA"
            }
            [2]=>
            object(stdClass)#15859 (5) {
              ["id"]=>
              int(166)
              ["nome"]=>
              string(21) "Gerência de Sistemas"
              ["sigla"]=>
              string(5) "GESIS"
              ["unidades"]=>
              array(0) {
              }
              ["tipo"]=>
              string(14) "ADMINISTRATIVA"
            }
          }
          ["tipo"]=>
          string(14) "ADMINISTRATIVA"
        }
  }
```

This information will be loaded into WP-Admin to allow user selection when Filling in custom fields on a page

Field "Comarca" => receive [comarca]

Field "Unidade" => receive [unidade]

Field "sertor" => receive [nome] after selecting [comarca] and [unidade] dynamically

Field “sigla” => receive [sigla]

Field "Tipo" => receive [tipo]

Field "Pai" => Level of Object // A way to identify the object's level, to allow navigating

I tried foreach, array_walk_recursive(), but I couldn't extract the data from this object.

Comment: So what data do you need? Just use `$object->unidades[0]->unidades[0]->nome`?

Comment: If you create some PHP code that creates an object and then ask how to access it that will be easier. Otherwise it will take a lot of time for someone to try to recreate what you have there. Then you can specifically which piece of data you want.  ?